# save multidimensional arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, csv

I have a Multidimensional ArrayList, composed of multiple rows of different length. I would like to save the ArrayList as a single tab-delimited file with multiple columns, in which each column corresponds to a specific row of the ArrayList. I have tried to come up with a solution, but the only thing I could think of is to save each ArrayList row in separate files.

The ArrayList is called "array" and it contains several rows of different length. Here is the code:

```
try {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("try"));
        output.print(array.get(0));
    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In this case, I can save the first row of the ArrayList as a single file. The other solution I have been thinking about is to loop through the rows, to get as many separate files as the row numbers. However, I would like to get a single file with multiple tab-delimited columns.

Answer (score 0):

Ecxuse me, my old answer was based on a wrong interpretation of your needs.
I made you an example code:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MulitArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> innerArrayList1;
        List<String> innerArrayList2;
        List<String> innerArrayList3;
        List<List> outerArrayList;
        
        innerArrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        innerArrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        innerArrayList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        //comic heros
        innerArrayList1.add("superman");
        innerArrayList1.add("batman");
        innerArrayList1.add("catwoman");
        innerArrayList1.add("spiderman");
        //historical persons
        innerArrayList2.add("Stalin");
        innerArrayList2.add("Gandy");
        innerArrayList2.add("Lincoln");
        innerArrayList2.add("Churchill");
        //fast food
        innerArrayList3.add("mc donalds");
        innerArrayList3.add("burger king");
        innerArrayList3.add("subway");
        innerArrayList3.add("KFC");
        
        //fill outerArrayList
        outerArrayList = new ArrayList<List>();
        outerArrayList.add(innerArrayList1);
        outerArrayList.add(innerArrayList2);
        outerArrayList.add(innerArrayList3);
        
        //print
        for(List<String> innerList : outerArrayList) {
            for(String s : innerList) {
                System.out.print(s + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        
    }

}
```

The result is:
[image: result of my mulitarray print]

As you can see, the results are printed with tabs, but the space between them differentiate. You can write it the same way into your file, but this is not the best way to save data. I hope I could help you bit, greetings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to use your code, but it doesn't work. The final file I got contains just 1 row of the ArrayList. I guess the problem is that I have a multidimentional ArrayList (an ArrayList of Arraylists).

Comment: No its my bad, I though of an 1-dimensional arraylist, but as you said, you meand a 2-dimensional arraylist.